# Eclipse not showing 'Domainmodel Content-Type' in Preferences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext, eclipse-emf, domain-model

I am following a tutorial for Xtext/EMF were I need to select in Preferences> General> Content Types> Text > Domainmodel Content-Type in the Eclipse IDE.

I created a Xtext project, but it does not appear.

How do I see this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What you get in that list depends a lot on exactly what plug-ins you have installed in Eclipse. Does the tutorial say anything about which Eclipse package or plug-ins it is based on?

Comment: Have you literally only created a project? You haven't deployed it, yet?

Comment: The tutorial is from the Xtext documentation: https://eclipse.dev/Xtext/documentation/340_lsp_support.html I can run my DSL at runtime with my program in a file .mydsl, but "Domain Context-Type" still not appearing. Thank

Comment: Did you install https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.lsp4e as described in the tutorial?